# asp:Button text attribute causing validation error

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, button, .net-3.5

Long time reader, first time asker. Anywho the problem I am having is that i have a few buttons that is causing issue with the page validator. I have been asked not to change their text attribute if i can avoid to and not to turn off the ValidateRequest attribute.

the error i am getting is " The entered value "<<" is potentially dangerous and not acceptable.

an example button is.

```
<asp:Button id="testFirstButton" width="25" Font-Size="8pt" runat="server" Text="<<" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
```

this is one of my test buttons i did to make sure it was the button and not code behind or anything else. sure enough this one didn't past.

Comment: I just created an empty page with one Button just like the one in your code and I didn't get any errors. Maybe it conflicts with other elements of the page. Can you post some more code of your .aspx page?

Comment: I unfortunately can't put more of the code up. Wish i could, but it is against policy.

Comment: I understand that. One thing I would try is to start removing other elements of the page (one at the time), until the error stops. One of the elements removed (probably the last one) is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
Text="<<"
```

Try using

```
Text="&lt;&lt;"
```

This will display the same text for the button and should avoid validation errors

Comment: I just tried to put this in and still got the same error. which is bizarre to say the least. thank you though

Comment: It is weird, something else must be going on, check the rest of your page for presence of angle brackets in other places

Answer (score -1):

Try put 
`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` 
 in your Web.config file and add your page 
 `ValidateRequest="false"`.

Note: It works but may cause some security issues.

Comment: I am not aloud to do that on this one. Thanks though